# Localizar dia da semana especifico dentre datas

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho o seguinte código para lançar em uma agenda dias e horários disponíveis e para isso uso a seguinte rotina:

```
    //recebo dados do formulario
    //inclusive o dia da semana ex.: Friday
    $dia_semana = $_POST['dia_semana'];
    $hora = $_POST['hora']; 
    $laboratorio = $_POST['laboratorio'];
    $quantidade = $_POST['quantidade']-1;

    //pega a data de hoje
    //para verificar qual a proxima data correspondente ao
    //dia enviado pelo formulario
    // como por exemplo, proxima sexta(Friday)
    $hoje = date('Y-m-d');
    $dia = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$hoje next $dia_semana"));

        $dados = array(
            'data' => $dia,
            'hora' => $hora,
            'laboratorio' => $laboratorio
        );
        //cadastra no banco a primeira data usando minha funcao
        $cadastrar = DBCreate('nw_vip',$dados);

      //faz um loop para cadastrar as proximas datas
      //com o dia escolhido limitado a quantidade
      //passada pelo formulario
      for($i=0;$i<$quantidade;$i++)
      {
       //se a primeira sexta caiu no dia 10
       //caucula as proximas somando 7 dias e cadastrando
       $dia =  date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$dia +7 day"));
       $dados = array(
         'data' => $dia,
         'hora' => $hora,
         'laboratorio' => $laboratorio
       );
      //cadastra no banco usando e minha função
      $cadastrar = DBCreate('nw_vip',$dados);
}
```

Meu problema se eu lançar 5 sextas feiras hoje e depois lançar mais 5 sextas, ele vai repetir as datas.

Então eu precisaria que na segunda vez que eu fosse lançar ele pudesse considerar a ultima sexta já cadastrada caso haja alguma e registrar a partir dela.

Exemplo: Lanço 3 Sextas as 8hs:

```
Sex 24/06 8:00
Sex 01/07 8:00
Sex 08/07 8:00
```

Se mais tarde eu lançar novamente mais 5 que a próxima continuasse da sexta dia 15/08. Como realizar um consulta para saber a data da ultima sexta feira já cadastrada, conforme meu exemplo. Claro que poderia ser outro dia e até outro horário.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma consulta na sua tabela **procurando a última ocorrência de data do dia da semana** que está tentando agendar. Para o exemplo da sexta-feira fica assim:

```
SELECT MAX(data_agenda) AS ultima_data
  FROM minha_agenda
 WHERE WEEKDAY(data_agenda) = 5; 
/* semana iniciando em 0 para domingo, então 5 é sexta-feira, ok? */
```

Você pode mudar a *query* para o `WHERE` contemplar **mais restrições**, como horário, laboratório, ou qualquer outra informação que desejar.

O resultado da consulta será sempre a última data no seu contexto. **Se resultar vazio**, significa que você **ainda não tem registro** e pode iniciar com o próprio dia informado pelo usuário.

Informações sobre a função `WEEKDAY` aqui: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday

**Observação**: também é possível usar a função [DAYOFWEEK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek), que usa o padrão de semana iniciado em 1 para domingo, 2 para segunda-feira e assim por diante.

Comment: A função MAX nesse contexto me retorna a data 'mais alta', no caso a que esta mais distante no futuro?

Comment: A função te retorna a maior data que encontrar na tabela do banco de dados, para as restrições que você determinou na query. Inclusive datas no futuro já registradas na tabela.